# How to stop timer from retrying in Weblogic 10.3 (EE container) when transaction is rolled back due to SQLException (timeout)?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x, jta

Basically i have EJB3 timer calling another EJB 3 (DAO) - this call is wrapped in catch block. The other EJB throws timeout SQL Exception when tries to acquire a connection to DS (throws exception to caller). In the logs i see that this timeout is keep on trying to execute again and again. What options are there to prevent it from trying again?

```
..
// Timer
@Timeout
public void timeout(Timer timer) { // keeps on coming here 
...
try {

 dao.processJob();
} catch (SQLException) { // catches the timeout
log
}

// dao
@Resource(...)
private Datasource ds

public void process() throws SQLException {
ds.getConnection() // throws timeout here
..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Documentation :

> if a bean cancels a timer within a transaction that gets rolled back, the timer 
>   cancellation is rolled back. In this case, **the timer’s
>   duration is reset as if the cancellation had never occurred**.

Therefore, the timer probably doesn't get cancelled. This may be the probable reason to retry continuously.

- You can try to catch the exception in `process` method, instead of throwing it & can return `null`.
- Alternatively, you can have `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` for method `process`, which will be part of new transaction.

Comment: TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW is what i am looking for. Thank you.